# Returning string from function having multiple NULL '\0' in C

Tags: c, string, compression, clr

I am compressing string. And the compressed string sometimes having NULL character inside before the end NULL. I want to return the string till the end null.But the compressor function is returning the sting till the occurring of the first NULL. Please help me.

```
char* compressor(char* str)
    {
      char *compressed_string;
      //After some calculation
      compressed_string="bk`NULL`dk";// at the last here is automatic  an NULL we all know
    return compressed_string;
    }
void main()
   {
    char* str;
    str=compressor("Muhammad Ashikuzzaman");
    printf("Compressed Value = %s",str);

   }
```

The output is : Compressed Value = bk;
And all other characters from compressor function is not here. Is there any way to show all the string.

Comment: Be careful when returning pointers from functions, if the pointer `compressed_string` is really an array then you're returning a pointer to a local variable which goes out of scope once the function returns.

Comment: Yeah, C 'strings' suck and cannot hold nul chars, ie. they are essentialy unfit for purpose.

Comment: You should return it as a vector<char>, char* and std::string are not good for binary data

Comment: Also, is the string you return *actually* a string, or just binary data? If it's binary data you can no longer treat it as a string.

Comment: You have to return the buffer data and the size, so `std::vector<char>` does the job.

Comment: @marcin std::string can hold binary data just fine.

Comment: thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have put c at the last of the question. But you can do it with c or c++ any . If I get the answer I will do with one of them.. Thanks

Comment: @Muhammad Then write two questions. These are different languages with _very_ different answers for them. Tag the question with whichever language your project is written in, then forget the other one!

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am using CLR. I can do here c or C++ any. Will I tag CLR and remove c and C++. please inform me..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, but dont expect c_str() to return correct data

Comment: Will I do the same question in c++ and c# differently. Because I had to do that @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @marcin_j - The `c_str()` function will return the correct data.  The responsibility of interpreting the data correctly is on the programmer.  The `size()` member function tells you exactly the number of characters that the string actually consists of, and c_str() always returns all of the data.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman - In your function, how do you know what the size is of the compressed data?  You have no indication of the size when that function returns, so that string is basically useless without size information attached to it in some way.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my point is that using string for that might be error prone, clients of your function must know that this string content needs special treatment.

Comment: Thanks @ PaulMcKenzie . When I am compressing the data I am counting each character postion and make an compressed vale of that data. With that variable I am keeping track with the number of character in my compressed bit.

Comment: Ok, At this time I am making question for also C# now. because my project is all about those language. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman - `With that variable I am keeping track with the number of character in my compressed bit.`  Yes, but the outside functions needs to know the size of the data, and your code doesn't show how this is communicated.  Look at my answer using `std::string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* func(char *str, int *length)
        {
          int i;
          *length=9;//Put string length you calculated
          str=(char*)malloc(*length*sizeof(char));
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        str[i]=i+65;
        str[5]=0;
        str[6]=65;
        str[7]=67;
        str[8]=0;   
          return str;
        }
int main()
{
    char *str;
    int i,length=0; 
    str=func("Muhammad Ashikuzzaman",&length); 
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
         printf("%c",str[i]);
    scanf("%d",&i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns "entire string". It is printf that outputs it until the null character will be encountered.

You could define the function the following way

```
char * compressor( const char* source, size_t *result_len );
```

To understand the problem consider the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * compressor( const char* source, size_t *result_len )
{
    char *compressed_string = "bk\0dk";
    *result_len = sizeof( "bk\0dk" );

    return compressed_string;
}


int main( void )
{
    char* str;
    size_t n;

    str = compressor( "Muhammad Ashikuzzaman", &n );

    int i;
    printf( "Compressed Value = " );

    for ( char *p = str; n; n -= i + 1, p += i + 1 )
    {
        i = printf( "%s", p );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Compressed Value = bkdk
```

Comment: Actually I don't know the real value of compressed_string. Because it will different for each input. So can I put sizeof(compressed_string). Thanks. I liked your way and up voted it

Comment: @Muhammad Ashikuzzaman Each time you have to calculate it and return through the second parameter.

Comment: But at that time I think sizeof will not work. because it will calculate till the first NULL is n't it. Also please don't forget to appreciate the question if you think, Thanks.

Comment: @Muhammad Ashikuzzaman I used sizeof based on your code that to demonstrate an example. You have to calculate the size by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

std::string compressor(char* str)
{
   char *compressed_string;
   int len;  // this is the size of the compressed data
   //...
   // compress the data and assume that len has the number of characters
   //...
   std::string theString(compressed_string, len);
   // clean up any memory here.
   //...
   return theString;
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string str = compressor("Muhammad Ashikuzzaman");
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(cout,""));
}
```

Note the usage of std::string, as well as how the information is outputted using the `copy` algorithm function.  The reason why `copy` is used instead of `printf` is to ensure that all of the characters, including the (invisible) embedded NULL's are printed.

Also, the size of the compressed data is easily retrieved by calling `str::size()`.