# Returning string from function having multiple NULL '\0' in C++

Tags: c++, string, compression

I am compressing string. And the compressed string sometimes having NULL character inside before the end NULL. I want to return the string till the end null.But the compressor function is returning the sting till the occurring of the first NULL. I made a question for c before about it. But consecutively I need also the solution in C++ now, and in next C#. Please help me.Thanks.

```
char* compressor(char* str)
    {
      char *compressed_string;
      //After some calculation
      compressed_string="bk`NULL`dk";// at the last here is automatic  an NULL we all know
    return compressed_string;
    }
void main()
   {
    char* str;
    str=compressor("Muhammad Ashikuzzaman");
    printf("Compressed Value = %s",str);

   }
```

The output is : Compressed Value = bk;
And all other characters from compressor function is not here. Is there any way to show all the string.

Comment: Don't write shitty C in C++.

Comment: Didn't this answer the question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835422/returning-string-from-function-having-multiple-null-0-in-c/25839786#25839786. Not only does that answer return the string with all the nulls, it prints the entire string, including the nulls (even though they will be invisible).

Comment: @Puppy I need it in c++ also.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried your one with C but #Lightness Races in Orbit told me to do it with C++ in difference question. But now I am trying your one with C++. But I also need one for C#. Will it be the same with your one in C# string. Then I will not need to question again. And will I delete this question? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @PaulMcKenzie I tried Vlad From Moscow's anser and Shiam Answer from my previous answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie please answer here. I had understand your one now. But I actually did the previous question for c. And this is for C++ now. Actually I am in hogh pressure with my thesis project of undergraduate with this topics.

Comment: Instead of asking us to write code for you, have you considered heeding some advice? You've been told at the previous question that you cannot use C strings. Your real problem is that strings hold text data not binary data. You appear to be burying your head in the sand and refusing to heed advice because you feel pressured. But instead of helping your finish sooner, this will delay you.

Comment: Actually I am doing it now. But for the helping other people I made this question. And I did see only Shiam Rahman And vilad from moscow's answer. And  Lightness Races in Orbit told me it is different case in c and c++ so I did that. Sorry I have got the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/25839786/3399176 now. But I changed the tag of that question only c. thanks.

Comment: If you suggest I am deleting this question.Because i also want to see stackoverflow is full-of essential unique data.And people get solution with one click. As I get sometimes. thanks @DavidHeffernan

Comment: Use `std::string` not `char *`.  `std::string` doesn't have a problem with '\0' in its contents.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem that you have is that compression algorithms operate on binary data rather than text. If you compress something, then expect some of the compressed bytes to be zero. Thus the compressed data cannot be stored in a null-terminated string.

You need to change your mindset to work with binary data.

To compress do the following:

1. Convert from text to binary using some well-defined encoding. For instance, UTF-8. This will yield an array of `unsigned char`.
2. Compress the `unsigned char`, which will again yield an array of `unsigned char`, but now compressed.

To decompress you just reverse these steps.

Since you are writing C++ code you would be well advised to use standard containers. Such as `std::string` or `std::wstring` and `std::vector<T>`.

The exact same principles apply in all languages. When you come to code this in C#, you need to convert from text to binary. Use `Encoding.GetBytes()` to do that. That yields a byte array, `byte[]`. Compress that to another byte array. And so on.

But you really must first overcome this desire to attempt to store binary data in text data types.